# Build-in query persist?

Tags: 8, database

Is there a default Drupal 8 database persist function? Like as for Doctrine.

```
for($i=1;$i<100;$i++) {
    $query->persist();
}

$query->flush();
```

I want to collect first a lot of data and bulk send it to the database.

The code I am using now is the following.

```
$db = \Drupal::database();    
foreach($response->customer_products as $itemCode) {
    $productNode = $this->loadObjectProduct($itemCode);
    $db->insert('customer_product')
           ->fields([
              'card_code' => $cardCode,
              'item_code' => $productNode->id()
           ])
       ->execute();
}
```

That requires too much memory, and it fires a lot of queries.

Is there some way to collect the queries and bulk-send it to the database?

Comment: What is an `$itemCode` in relation to the `$productNode`?

Comment: Not sure since I don't know doctrine, but you might be looking for https://www.drupal.org/node/310079#multi-insert-form. That's D7, but it's pretty much identical in D8.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to stuff more values into a custom insert (or merge) by using the [values](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Query!InsertTrait.php/function/InsertTrait%3A%3Avalues/8.2.x) method. This isn't comparable to the persist functionality, and can only be used in limited scenarios such as a single table. A more complex storage scenario, such as with entities, would not be possible as a single entity save operation could be writing to multiple tables (unless someone rewrote a custom entity storage layer).

Also, I am not sure what the loadObjectProduct exactly does in your code, but this seems to be loading node entities. It would probably be best to use an Entity [Query::condition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Query!QueryBase.php/function/QueryBase%3A%3Acondition/8.1.x) and fetch back multiple entities.

Finally you need to use an array map/reduce to map the values.

Something like the following pseudo-code:

```
// Using Database static method from \Drupal\Core\Database\Database.
$database = Database::getConnection();
// Assumes loadObjectProduct is refactored.
$nodes = $this->loadObjectProducts($itemCode);
// I tend to think backwards about this sort of thing. :-)
$values = array_reduce($nodes, function (&$result, $productNode) use ($cardCode) {
  $result[] = [
    'card_code' => $cardCode,
    'item_code' => $productNode->id(),
  ];
  return $result;
}, []);

try {    
  $database->insert('customer_product')
    ->fields(['card_code', 'item_code'])
    ->values($values)
    ->execute();
}
catch (DatabaseWrapperException $e) {
  // Catch errors
}
```